# Hide Div under label using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

How do I hide the div `paymentProviderHeader-cc` with JavaScript (not jQuery) but without the help of those classes because there is another section in the page with the same divs/classes that I don't want to hide. The only unique selector I can use in this case is the attribute for in label (`for="radio-paypalcommerce"`).

I tried this but didn't work.

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("label[for="radio-paypalcommerce"] > .paymentProviderHeader-cc")[0].style.visibility = "hidden";
```

```html
<div class="form-field">
  <label for="radio-paypalcommerce" class="form-label optimizedCheckout-form-label">
    <div class="paymentProviderHeader-container">
      <div class="paymentProviderHeader-nameContainer" data-test="payment-method-paypalcommerce">
      </div>
      <div class="paymentProviderHeader-cc">
      </div>
    </div>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: I've edited your question so that your code is now a snippet that can be run directly from your question.

Comment: Why not directly accessing the class like `document.getElementsByClassName("paymentProviderHeader-cc")[0].style.visibility = "hidden";` ??

Comment: First, check your quotes in `"label[for="radio-paypalcommerce"] > .paymentProviderHeader-cc"`. Also, this is not a className, check out [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) instead of  `getElementsByClassName()` and last: `paymentProviderHeader-cc` is **not** a direct child of the `label`, your css selector is not correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several things wrong with your code:

**1.)** You are calling `document.getElementsByClassName` but you are passing in a full CSS selector. That method can only be given a class name, which is why it's named that way.  If you want to use a full CSS selector use `document.querySelector` or `document.querySelectorAll` instead

**2.)** Your CSS selector string uses the same quotes inside the string as you use to quote the string itself. This is why you have a syntax error. See below where I use `'` single quotes for the whole string and then keep the `"` inside for the `for="..."` selector.

```
'label[for="radio-paypalcommerce"] > .paymentProviderHeader-cc'
```

**3.)** Lastly your selector is looking for `.paymentProviderHeader-cc` as a **direct child** of the `label`. It's not a direct child, it's inside the `.paymentProviderHeader-container` element.  So you can either remove the `>` so that it finds a child nested at any level (which is what I recommend), or you can add the extra selector in there like this

```
'label[for="radio-paypalcommerce"] > .paymentProviderHeader-container > .paymentProviderHeader-cc'
```

Here's a full working example

```js
document
  .querySelector('label[for="radio-paypalcommerce"] .paymentProviderHeader-cc')
  .style.visibility = "hidden";
```

```html
<div class="form-field">
  <label for="radio-paypalcommerce" class="form-label optimizedCheckout-form-label">
    <div class="paymentProviderHeader-container">
      <div class="paymentProviderHeader-nameContainer" data-test="payment-method-paypalcommerce">
      </div>
      <div class="paymentProviderHeader-cc">
      </div>
    </div>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer Chris, I appreciate it :)